# curl issue when moving from apache to IIS

Tags: php, curl, iis

We have a curl call to a website, but after moving this website from an Apache server to an IIS server it stopped working. Now it always give me a **Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)** error.

I have researched this error and some people talked about spaces on the URL, but there are none.

Here is my code:

```
$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['d'] = $date;
$data_to_post['u'] = $username;
$data_to_post['a'] = $activities;
$data_to_post['h'] = $homework;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-type: multipart/form-data"
));
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_POST => sizeof($data_to_post),
        CURLOPT_URL => MY_URL,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_to_post
));

$data = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

It works when I try to POST using https://www.hurl.it/

I'm posting from another domain.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After almost the entire day looking for it, I was able to solve my problem with a workaround. Instead of using CURL, I'm now using **file_get_contents** (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) to do the POST.